# Custom Java method to remove substring - weird behavior on removing quotes

Tags: java, string, methods

I am trying to create a general remove String method which takes two String inputs - parentString and cleanable, and it returns parentString back after completely removing cleanable of all it occurrences in the parentString, which works pretty fine except when I tell it to remove the quotes.

. Here's what I did:

```
public String remove(String parentString, String cleanable) {
    int i = parentString.indexOf(cleanable);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "print index " + i);
    String child1, child2;


    while (parentString.indexOf(cleanable) != -1) {
        if (parentString.indexOf(cleanable) == 0) {
            child1 = "";
        } else {
            child1 = parentString.substring(0, (i - 1));
        }
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "print child1 " + child1);
        child2 = parentString.substring(i + cleanable.length(), parentString.length() - 1);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "print child2 " + child2);
        parentString = child1 + child2;
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "print parent " + parentString);
    }

    return parentString;

}
```

It works fine except for when the input is in the form ["J.K. Rowling"] and I apply the method as author = remove(author, "\""); It gives the following values:

```
child1 = "" ;
child2= K. Rowling;
```

I also noticed that the substring(x,y) method is returning "" when x is becoming equal to y. ? This method I have created is behaving in a manner I do not understand, even when I am using simple logic. I know there are already methods available which will do what I am trying to do, but I'd like this method to work.

Comment: You should be more explicit one what you are doing and what is it suppose to do. See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: PS : _I have to parse JSON data in my program_ don't do it yourself, use existing API that are more complex that you could imagine

Comment: Can you add some example of function parameters and expected results?

Comment: why not simply use the replace method?

Comment: @xtremeBaumer I am still in learning phase and I enjoy creating methods which save me a lot of work as well as help me learn the concepts.

Comment: I have edited the question details, I hope it is clear now what I am trying to do.

Comment: i have added an answer which might suit your needs

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the full process - it'd better if you implement your search of substring and method `substring`.
The method returns an empty string when `x` equals to y because `x` - it's a start position and `y` - it's end position (exclusive), so you ask: "give me a string from 5 to 5", of course it'll return you an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
 public class HelloWorld
    {
      public String remove(String parentString, String cleanable) {
        int i = parentString.indexOf(cleanable);
        String child1, child2;
        while (parentString.indexOf(cleanable) != -1) {
            if (parentString.indexOf(cleanable) == 0) {
                child1 = "";
            } else {
                child1 = parentString.substring(0, (i - 1));
            }
            child2 = parentString.substring(i + cleanable.length(), parentString.length() - 2);
            parentString = child1 + child2;
        }
        return parentString;
    }
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
       System.out.print(new HelloWorld().remove("[\"J.K. Rowling\"]","\""));
      }
    }
```

**Output**

```
J.K. Rowling
```

Comment: input should be `String parent="[\"J.K. Rowling\"]";` and only the escaped `"` shall be removed

Comment: @XtremeBaumer  check answer i replace `child2 = parentString.substring(i + cleanable.length(), parentString.length() - 1);` this one to `child2 = parentString.substring(i + cleanable.length(), parentString.length() - 2);`

Answer (score 0):

There are two points:

```
child1 = parentString.substring(0, (i - 1));
```

because of this, your child1 will become *""*  as the first *"* will be at 1st position .

then second point:

```
    child2 = parentString.substring(i + cleanable.length(), parentString.length() - 1);
```

i = 1

cleanable.length() = 1

so it will be *J.K. Rowling"* in first iteration and in next iteration,
child1 will still be *""* because of

```
child1 = parentString.substring(0, (i - 1));
```

but this time

```
child2 = parentString.substring(i + cleanable.length(), parentString.length() - 1);
```

it will remove 1 (i=1) + 1(cleanable.length()) = 2 characters from it. and *"* from last.

hence output will be K.Rowling

Answer (score 0):

so i created a simple method for you, which only allows 1 char to be replaced at a time. if you want more than 1 char to be removed, you will need some other logic

```
String t = "[\"J.K. Rowling\"]";
String t2 = "\"";
for (int i = 0; i < t.length(); i++) {
    if (t.charAt(i) == t2.charAt(0)) {
        t = t.substring(0, i) + t.substring(i + 1);
    }
}
System.out.println(t);
```

this will remove the first character of `t2` in `t`. if you need any further help feel free to ask

for longer string to replace this works:

```
String t = "[\"J.K. Rowling\"]";
String t2 = "[\"J.K";
for(int i=0;i<t.length()-t2.length();i++){
    if(t.substring(i, i+t2.length()).equals(t2)){
        t=t.substring(0,i)+t.substring(i+=t2.length());
    }
}
System.out.println(t);
```

its your choice what you will use